# vue.js sl-vue-tree モジュールの修正

Tags: javascript, html5, typescript, vue.js

この質問はマルチポストです。
スタックオーバーフローはマルチポスト禁止ではないということなので、質問させて頂きます。
元の質問はこちらです。↓
https://teratail.com/questions/141695

---

現在、こちらのvue.js用の、配列をドラッグ&ドロップして並び替えるモジュールを使っております。↓

https://github.com/holiber/sl-vue-tree

しかしこちらのモジュール、配列の中のオブジェクトが持つ"関数"が、ドラッグ&ドロップ時に消えてしまいます。
それは、自分が以前したこちらの質問↓によって判明致しました。

https://teratail.com/questions/140995

そこで、モジュールの修正を今やろうとしてます。

今、自分のgitにフォーク、さらにそれをローカルにクローンし、ソースツリーでgit管理できてる状態です。
初めてフォークしました。

次に編集してから、npm run buildし、新しくできたsl-vue-treeのモジュールを、プッシュしました。

sl-vue-treeは以下のように編集しました。

こちらのモジュールを使い↓
https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone

```
var clone = require('clone');

copy(entity) {
    return clone(entity)
},
```

そして自分が開発している環境(vue-cli3.0)のpackage.jsonを

```
"dependencies": {
        "sl-vue-tree": "git+https://github.com/my-name/sl-vue-tree#master",
```

このように変えました。

そしてnpm installをしました。

しかし開発環境で npm run serveより起動してみると、
ちゃんと関数ごとディープコピーはされていたのですが、以下のコンソールエラーが出てしまいました。

Invalid default value for prop "multiselectKey": Props with type Object/Array must use a factory function to return the default value.

found in

--->  at src/sl-vue-tree.vue

このエラーについて調べてみたのですが、

https://github.com/zuobaiquan/vue/issues/4

こちらの記事を見る感じ、関数はアロー関数にしなくてはいけないのでしょうか。
ただ、自分は関数を含んだオブジェクトのpropは他の箇所で普通にやっております。

質問したいこととしては、

1.このコンソールエラーをどうやって消すか。
2.元のライブラリ(sl-vue-tree)にプルリクというのをしてみたいが、上のような他のライブラリを使う方法でプルリクしてもいいのか。

です。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 複数の質問が含まれている様なので、聞きたいことを整理して要点を箇条書きにしたり、個別の質問に分割することを検討してください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。承知致しました、今から少し編集します。

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51958950/error-message-props-with-type-object-array-must-use-a-factory-function-to-retu/51959056#51959056 昨日、英語版のスタックオーバーフローで教えてもらいました。
報告が遅れてしまい、申し訳ございません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

英語版ほスタックオーバーフローで教えてもらいました。
報告が遅れてしまい、申し訳ございません。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51958950/error-message-props-with-type-object-array-must-use-a-factory-function-to-retu

```
multiselectKey: {
type: [String, Array],
default: function () {
  return ['ctrlKey', 'metaKey']
},
validator: function (value) {
    let allowedKeys = ['ctrlKey', 'metaKey', 'altKey'];
    let multiselectKeys = Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value];
    multiselectKeys = multiselectKeys.filter(keyName => allowedKeys.indexOf(keyName ) !== -1);
    return !!multiselectKeys.length;
  }
},
```

sl-vue-tree.jsの上の部分をこのように変更することで直りました...。
理屈はあまりよく分かっておりませんが...。

Answer (score 0):

> しかしこちらのモジュール、配列の中のオブジェクトが持つ"関数"が、ドラッグ&ドロップ時に消えてしまいます。

[sl-vue-tree](https://github.com/holiber/sl-vue-tree)というモジュールのREADMEを見てみましたが、以下のように `serializable` とあるのでこれは仕様と思われます。

```
data?: TDataType; // any serializable user data
```

仕様を変更してはいけないわけではありません。特に上位互換性が保てるならば。
しかし、現状なぜこの仕様になっているのかは理解した上で変更した方がよいでしょう。

Vueに詳しくないのでここからは想像ですが、そもそもVueの仕様か慣習により、データ（Vueインスタンスの `data` プロパティ）には関数オブジェクトを含めないことになっているからではないでしょうか。
まずは、Vueのデータに関数オブジェクトを保存してよいものなのか確認した方がよさそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。特に動作に問題ない上にエラーも消せましたので、上位互換性は持ててるような気がします...。ただ自分はフォークを初めてやり、プルリクはやったことがないので、今の状態でプルリクしていいのかどうかに関しては、よろしければご意見伺いたいです...。

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51958950/error-message-props-with-type-object-array-must-use-a-factory-function-to-retu/51959056#51959056 昨日、英語版のスタックオーバーフローで教えてもらいました。
報告が遅れてしまい、申し訳ございません。

Comment: 私のプルリクに関しての意見は、Vueのデータに関数オブジェクトを保存してよいものなのか確認してからのほうが良さそうだ、というものです。たまたま今動いているかどうかではなく、仕様や慣習として許されているか、です。私はこれ以上は解らないので、不安でしたら、別途質問や問合せをなさるとよいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！
https://jp.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html
これを見る限り、

propE: {
      type: Object,
      // オブジェクトもしくは配列のデフォルト値は
      // 必ずそれを生み出すための関数を返す必要があります。
      default: function () {
        return { message: 'hello' }
      }
    },

Comment: すみません、コメント途中で追加してしまいました。https://jp.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%91%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%AA%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3
これを見る限り、関数をpropsしてるように見えますので、プルリクしてみようかなと思います...。ありがとうございました。